# Can people have free time without technology?

Tags: society, history

I read a lot of answers about historical stuff in here, they go something like this

''X and Y would never happen because people back then were working 800 million hours per day and couldn't waste resources or time for such activities''

But is it actually true? Did villagers and peasants  live basically like numb slaves with no hobbies before the invention  of industry?

or should the question be, how true or false is it?

Comment: What do you mean by technology? (A rock used to open a nut would be a basic form of technology.) Kings and nobles always had free-time, even before the industrial revolution. Even slaves (mandated conscripts) in ancient Egypt had some time to spare outside work. Can you [edit] to clarify what you mean - and to give us some societal and worldbuilding context.

Comment: While knowing whether peasants/serfs/slaves had free time or not is useful to create worlds, it's history, not worldbuilding ^^.

Comment: Besides you need to clarify and/or focus the era and place you're interested in. Historically, people weren't the same with the same lifestyle in very ancient China, early America or old Africa ^^.

Comment: I recommend asking about working schedules on the history stack exchanges. You will get better answers and you could even focus on specific regions and time periods

Comment: In other words, was their a time in history when tavern keepers went bankrupt because low-class people were so busy working that they had no time to go to the pub for a drink? No, there was never a time when low-class people were so busy working that they had no time to go to the pub for a drink. VTC because of the most strange assumption that there was an "invention of industry", and that there was a time in history before the "invention of industry".

Comment: I hate to bring up Morris-dancing, but globally there's lots that goes [back ages](https://listverse.com/2017/02/04/10-mysterious-ancient-dances/) into history. Tribal rhythmic-music/dance may well have been the first artform. There's always time for dancing.

Comment: Lions have lots of free time and have zero technology.

Comment: I don't have any links or references to back it up, but I remember reading that hunter gatherer societies had nearly 50% downtime.

Comment: Can you give any examples of the answers you mentioned?  The drastic way you described it certainly doesn't sound as if it makes sense, but possibly they were referring to something more specific that made more sense.  (Or possibly they just didn't know what they were talking about  :-D  ).

Comment: I recommend moving this question to the History stack exchange question.  While you might want this information for worldbuilding there is no element of world building present in the question as asked.  Frankly your get much better answers from actual historians then we could give anyways.

Answer (score 10):

[According to some highly influential anthropologists, technology actually inhibits our free time rather than facilitate it.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_affluent_society) People have always had downtime in between tasks, and people in the past had natural lulls in between hunts or times of gathering. There were only so many spear points to knap and so many baskets to weave.

> Did villagers and peasants live basically like numb slaves with no hobbies before the invention of industry?

No, they did not, and this is made apparent by the staggering number of Christian holidays that medieval peasants observed with festivities in the Middle Ages. Not to mention that the sabbath was a moral and legal requirement for Jews stretching back millennia. Shooting clubs for crossbows were popular in the HRE  and the Low Counties during the Middle Ages. English yeomen had to be compelled to practice archery by making some of their sports forbidden on the sabbath. Various “football” games existed in medieval Europe that were insanely violent by modern standards but super popular. On the Central Asian steppe, horse racing, polo and [throwing a dead sheep around while competing with the other guys on horseback](https://www.wired.com/story/knock-around-goat-carcass-with-buzkashi-players/amp) were super popular.

Comment: The theory you quote has lots of criticism.  The person making it considered time spent on hunting and gathering only, and not time spent on say collecting fireword, building and repairing homes, creating baskets, clothes, and other necessities etc.  We use money to pay for all that stuff to be done by others, they had to do it all themselves, or barter for it.  It's not fair to compare the majority of all our work in employment to only a portion of the work hunter/gather's did.

Comment: This also ignores the difference in quality of life.  The only reason hunter & gathers were successful was because their population stayed low enough to not consume resources faster then they naturally replenished themselves.  That population stayed low due to absurdly high child mortality rates, frequent deaths from easily preventable diseases etc.  Sure they may have had some free time, while starving, sick, cold, and morning the most recent child that died, but I think I'll accept an extra hour of work to avoid all that stuff thank you very much.

Comment: @dsollen While your criticisms of the hypothesis as a whole are valid, the simple fact of the matter is that primitive people did in fact have free time

Answer (score 5):

This is not really a Worldbuilding question, but.. of course. You haven't defined 'technology', but it doesn't actually matter. Humans have had free time for as long as there have been humans.

Without free time, humans would not have been able to [generate art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistoric_art), [music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistoric_music), [play games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_games) or indeed invent the technology you're talking about.

What is needed to support leisure time is an abundance of food/resources. Even in a hunter-gatherer society this is possible, either by luck or because a society might allocate resources unevenly.

Comment: "society might allocate resources unevenly" -- This is the driver of more or less free time. If your ruler is a despot king in ancient times or a despot CEO in modern times, then you're probably not going to have a lot of free time because they are taking the resources.

Comment: Sure, but the despot will!

Comment: Recent history has made it clear that despots have a lot of time for tweeting.

Answer (score 1):

Is herding goats "technology"? Or a sharpened stick? Digging a pit to trap a deer we can kill with thrown rocks and sharpened sticks? How about a net made of vines?

There is a tribe of chimpanzees, living near a coast, and there are ants in the sand near the coast. The chimps will scoop out handfuls of sand near the water, so a hole fills up with seawater. Then they drop a double handful of the sand with the ants in it, into their little puddle. The sand sinks, and the ants float, and the chimp sucks up the ants on the surface and eats them.

That's a form of technology! They made a tool and used it. Of course there's no telling how long they've done it; they learn by example, and this tool (a puddle) obviously leaves no fossil evidence; it is destroyed by use and the next tide.

I will presume by "technology" you mean in the modern colloquial sense of at least forged iron weapons, not the primitive type of rocks, sharp sticks,  plant fibers (like linen, easily made from the fibers of the flax plant) to make rope and nets, and holes in the ground.

In this case, I'd point to early goat herding, one of the oldest practices we know of. Goats are fantastically versatile. Relatively small and docile, they can eat any sort of vegetation including weeds, roots with dirt on them, wood, etc. Female goats produce highly nutritious milk, and goats breed relatively fast. Young males can be slaughtered for meat about the time they become aggressive; as can the elderly females and males. You only need a few males to keep the females breeding, and the herd grows quickly.

So you have plenty of fat and protein in the form of milk and occasional meat, and you just lead your goats about through brush and grasslands. You can supplement that with hunting and trapping of birds and small animals, and in a good environment, gathering of edible plants, root and fruit once in awhile. Both on land and near water, nets and other stick traps can capture small game and fish.

Archaeologists have found the remains of a clever fish trap off the coast of an island, made entirely from sticks a few inches wide driven into the sea floor. It is just off the coast, and shaped into a line that ends in a circle; kind of like the mirror image of the letter P. Swimming with the current, fish travel the line, but get trapped in the circle at the end. They can't just swim back out, they can't swim against the current, and the larger fish can't fit through the gaps between the sticks. So every day, the trap would fill up with larger fish, there to be netted or speared.

That would make finding enough food pretty easy.

There is a lot of evidence that primitive humans had down time. They made art, music, and other artifacts, and modern day hunter-gatherers are not working until they are frazzled. They do tend to be doing things all day, but they also have rich social lives: Unlike us, all of their entertainment is just each other.

Comment: Making pottery is obviously technology, and it predates iron working by many millennia.

Comment: @AlexP Agreed! The question is ill-defined as to what "technology" means. A sharpened stick is technology, crows make tools, so do chimps and dolphins. A flint knife is technology, a dug pit is technology. Heck, a campfire is technology that predates pottery.

We have to pick some threshold for the question since it doesn't provide one. I chose the development of iron tools, and stuck to "natural" tools and practices, which would include pottery of course.

Comment: yup, using a rock to smash open a coconut to get at the juice and meat inside is technology. Humans have no doubt been doing that for a hundred thousand years or more. Animals do it still. Gulls pick up shells and snails and drop them on the ground to get at the flesh inside.

Comment: @jwenting Exactly; without *any* form of technology for hunting, protection, warmth, keeping livestock (no fencing!) I question how long we'd survive; regardless of "free time".

Answer (score 1):

If someone is lazy enough, or rich, they can have as much leisure as they want, at least until they starve to death if poor, or lose all their money somehow.

And as far as I know, everyone in history had at least a tiny little bit of leisure time.  Even slaves who were worked to exaustion would proably take a few minutes to fall asleep duirng their rest periods, and might enjoy the feeling for those few minutes.